# OpenBts installation

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install OpenBts software on my laptop. After I type

```
svn co http://wush.net/svn/range/software/public
```

I get following:

> Authentication realm: http://wush.net:80 Subversion Login Username:

It asks me for username & password. Where to register for that? I try to register on wush.net but no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register on wush.net. Just try `sudo apt-get install subversion`, or this http://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/Tutorials/OpenBTSInstallation

Comment: When you answer with a link, you should include in your post the important information provided in the link, because if the distant website gets offline, your answer will not be useful.